# How to test UDP echo using nping

Tags: networking, udp

I need to test performance of UDP echo server application.

I use nping to generate traffic however nping always reports 100% packet loss no matter to which port the server returns the echo packets.

Nping works OK when I run it in ICMP mode but this does not tests the server.

Is there anything special about UDP echo packet to make it detectable by nping?

Comment: There is nothing known about your UDP echo server. What makes you think that it even works, i.e. how did you test it?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich My server returns the same UDP payload to the source port of nping. I checked it in Wireshark.

Comment: Could you please check with netcat, that the echoed data actually arrive at the client application?

Comment: Yes, the data arrives

Comment: No idea what you are exactly doing. I've made a small UDP echo server for testing, checked nping against it and it works without packet loss. nping does not have any special requirements here.

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear enough but I am asking about the the REPORT at the end of nping run. Does your nping reports 0% packet loss? What's the command line switches you run nping with? I have packets going both from and to nping but nping reports packet loss 100%

Comment: I just test with a local udp echo server `nping --udp -p 9999 127.0.0.1`. After exit (i.e. after I end nping with ^C) I get `UDP packets sent: 3 | Rcvd: 3 | Lost: 0 (0.00%)` - so nothing lost.